# Java: Looping array with for() with args[x]

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, optimization, args

I have this simple code, but wanna loop the args in order for each time the user wants to input data on it can be refreshed, can i do this with for()?  and if so... how i do implement this the best way possible?

```
class t1{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
System.out.println("Your name is: "+args[0]+" "+args[1]+" "+args[2]+" "+args[3]);   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
    System.out.print("Your name is:");
    for(String arg : args) {
        System.out.print(" " + arg);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it really helped!, can you explain the behaivior of for in this code?

Comment: This is known as an [Enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream`:

```java
String s = Arrays.stream(args)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(" "); // uses StringJoiner internally
System.out.println(s);
```

Or you can use `StringJoiner` directly:

```java
StringJoiner j = new StringJoiner(" ");
for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
  j.add(args[i]);
}
String s = j.toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing this is what you're trying to do...

```
StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();

for (String str: args) {
    strbuild.append(str).append("\n");
}

System.out.println("Your name is: " + strbuild);
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can! There are multiple ways to do this, and it works really well with for-loops. You can do it by using int variables, like this:

```
class t1 {  
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.print("Your name is: ");
    int arrayLength = args.length;
    for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++)
      System.out.println(" "+args[i]);        
  }
}
```

I think that's what you mean by for() with args[x].